# How to add Google Recaptcha for Zoo comments on Joomla1.5?

Tags: php, joomla, recaptcha

I want to add Captcha for the comments of my site. Because im getting lots of spam mails. Is there any way of using reCaptcha for Zoo comments ?   Is it possible to it using Google RECAPTCHA ? please advice

Answer (score 0):

There is no support natively for this. However there is a plugin for this on the Joomla Extension Directory [here](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/zoo-extensions/16235). Which you can install to give google captcha functionality

Comment: yes ..  but the thing it is 'commercial' im searching for a free option :)

Comment: its $12!! It would cost you more in time and effort to manually add it in (cause that's the only alternative) than to pay $12!